# `react-transition-group` evaluating both if AND else expressions on a ternary expression

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-transition-group

I have a component that renders a list, and this list of items can be increased. I'm wrapping the list around a `<TransitionGroup>` to animate new items being added.

There's a message when we don't have items on the list. However, even when items are added, the message won't go away. I tested it without `<TransitionGroup>` and it works normally. I have a [minimal example of the problem on CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/vibrant-khayyam-58n8z8?file=/src/App.js).

The code for the component is:

```js
const ItemsList = ({ items }) => {
  return (
    <TransitionGroup component="ul" timeout={400}>
      {items.length === 0
        ? "There is no items"
        : items.map((item, i) => (
            <CSSTransition key={i} classNames="item-animation">
              <li key={i}>{item}</li>
            </CSSTransition>
          ))}
    </TransitionGroup>
  );
};
```

After adding an element to the list, the message should disappear, but it's still visible.

[image: The message "there's no items" should not appear]

My guess is there's something different `react-transition-group` uses on render, not rendering the full component as we write it. But how to fix this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Try rendering `Transition Group` component only if `items.length !=0`

So your code should look something like this:

```
items.length !=0 ? `render your component` : "There is no item"
```

Comment: It correctly removes the "no items" message, but it also removes the animation of the first item being inserted. Kind of defeats the purpose of using `react-transition-group`, at least for the first element.